# Why do I have to wait two days to accept my own answer?

Tags: support, self-answer, accepted-answer

So I posted a question and then answered it(On normal Arqade) But when I hit the check mark it says *"You can not accept your answer for 2 days"* Why is this? I also searched the normal Arqade and the Meta for an answer.

Comment: Don't get hung up on (up or down) votes on meta: they aren't worth reputation and are usually more of a representation on the community's feelings toward the topic at hand rather than any meaning of quality. In your case it's probably because the answer is in the FAQ/Help Center :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ["Can I answer my own question?" FAQ in the Help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

> You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!

So the reason you need to wait before self-accepting is to encourage others to post their own answers to your question.